Как указать путь в views.py чтобы django понял, не используя абсолютный путь?
в определенный шаблон html мне нужно передать ссылку на картинку, ссылка хранится в json файле, проблема заключается в открытии файла django пишет что директория не найдена (путь относительный), хотя если создать файл python в той же директории что и файл с функциями ответов (views.py) и скопировать отрезок кода отвечающий за открытие файла то он сработает (это означает что ошибка не в пути), я предполагаю что проблема в относительном пути тк django использует эту функцию ответа в другом месте, но абсолютный путь писать не могу, как этого избежать? пример функции в файле views.py ниже
  def guess_page(request, category):
    if category in variations:
        with open(f'data_content/{category}.json') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            rand = random.randint(0, len(data))

        name = list(data)[rand]

        context = {
            'name': name,
            'picture': data[name]['picture'],
            'rate': data[name]['rate'],
            'category': category
        }

        return render(request, 'main/guess.html', context=context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()


Я абсолютно не уверен, но попробуйте использовать в начале пути ./

Для того, чтобы оставить ссылку на файл в вашем шаблоне (в вашем случае на картинку), корректнее будет использовать статические файлы
Оставил ссылку на документацию, т.к. материал достаточно объемный

Попробуйте использовать pathlib:
from pathlib import Path

DATA_FOLDER = Path('data_content')
...

def guess_page(request, category):
    if category in variations:
        with open(DATA_FOLDER / (category + '.json')) as file:
            ...

